# Unity, Rigidbody.MovePosition() is not working if transform.position is just changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

## Question

This code works. ↓

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(newPosition);
}
```

This code doesn't work. ↓

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

    Vector3 oldPosition = transform.position;
    transform.position = newPosition;
    transform.position = oldPosition;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(newPosition);
}
```

I tested in Unity 2019.4 and 2020.3.

So, it seems Rigidbody.MovePosition() will not work if transform.position just changed.
Why does this happen?

---

## Added 2021.9.3

I find that I can use [Physics.SyncTransforms()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) to solve the problem.

This code works. ↓

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

    Vector3 oldPosition = transform.position;
    transform.position = newPosition;
    transform.position = oldPosition;

    Physics.SyncTransforms();  //newly added

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(newPosition);
}
```

---

## Added 2023.9.2

**【Part1】**

Two years has past. These days I happen to deal with physics again.

I learned that [Rigidbody.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) is better than Transform.position if I want to change position directly.
And If used correctly, Rigidbody.position won't cause Rigidbody.MovePosition() to not function.

As @thekirmizi says, moving objects by both `Transform.position` and `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` is a lot far from best practice.

If I want to move a object in a continuous/physics way, I may use `Rigidbody.velocity`, `Rigidbody.AddForce` or `Rigidbody.MovePosition`.
A continuous/physics way means the object may collider with other RigidBody while moving and is then not moved to the destination.

If I want to move a object in a teleporting way, I may use `Transform.postion` or `Rigidbody.position`.
By this way the object is teleported (or jump) from one place to another.

Seldom would the continuous way and teleporting way be combined together.
If I'm farmilar with Unity's physics system, I should choose one way before coding.
(Of course I'm not farmilar with physics system 2 years ago, so I came to the awkward corner which I want to use both ways.)

【Part2】

Finally, why would transform.position change lead to Rigidbody>.MovePosition not function?
I can not be sure, but I can do some guess now.

**Internal Physics Update** In [ExecutionOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) is the real place where physics (e.g. physics move, collision and others) takes place.
That is to say, If I run Rigidbody.MovePosition, the rigidbody is not moved directly, it will be moved in Internal Physics Update. Before Internal Physics Update, the object is still at the old position, and after Internal Physics Update, it is moved to the new position.

I guess, If I run Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPosition), Unity gets a command from me which is to move the object from **oldPosition** to **newPosition**. Both oldPosition and newPosition are important.
(This is really a guess which has no evidence. It has a great opportunity to be wrong. The only goodness of it is that it may help me understand why Transform.move is incompatible with Rigidbody.MovePosition.)

In Internal Physics Update, when Unity is about to execute Rigidbody.MovePosition, he would check if the object is still at the oldPosition. The order is to move it from oldPosition to newPosition, if it is no longer at oldPosition, Unity would consider the order to be out-of-date and will not execute Rigidbody.MovePosition.

The position of oldPosition and newPosition are physics positions, which is Rigidbody.position.
So If code Rigidbody.MovePosition runs at **time1**, Internal Physics Update really executes Rigidbody.MovePosition at **time2**. Rigidbody.position must remains the same between time1 and time2.
So `Rigidbody.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); //Internal Physics Update` is OK, because Rigidbody.position changes before Rigidbody.MovePosition and there will be no change between time1 and time2.
But `Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); Rigidbody.position = oldPosition2; //Internal Physics Update` will result in MovePosition not functioning. Rigidbody.position is changed between time1 and time2.

Let's talk about `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); //Internal Physics Update`.
`Transform.position = oldPosition2` makes Transform.position and Rigidbody.position have different values, and the one of Transform.position is newer.
I guess in the first phase of Internal Physics Update, Unity will sync Transform.position and Rigidbody.position. If Transform.position has a newer value, Rigidbody.position would be assigned the newer value, which is oldPosition2 in the example.
Then when it is about to execute MovePosition, Unity find that Rigidbody.position is changed, so it is not executed.
This means `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); //Internal Physics Update` equals `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); Rigidbody.position = Transform.position; //The left of Internal Physics Update`.
Rigidbody.position is changed between time1 and time2.

`Transform.position = oldPosition2; Physics.SyncTransforms(); Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon);//Internal Physics Update` equals `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.position = Transform.position; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); //Internal Physics Update`.
Rigidbody.position has no change between time1 and time2.
So Physics.SyncTransforms() can help to make Transform.position and Rigidbody.MovePosition compatible.

In conclusion:

> `Rigidbody.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon);` ✔

> `Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon); Rigidbody.position = oldPosition2;` ❌

> `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon);` ❌

> `Transform.position = oldPosition2; Physics.SyncTransforms(); Rigidbody.MovePosition(newPositon);` ✔

That's all. That's my guess and my understanding after 2 years.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is in `c#`!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Rigidbody's MovePosition method should only be used if you're constantly checking for a collision/trigger whether if the rigid body attached to the game object has continuous/discrete collision detection. If you really are not using much physics in the project, avoid using it and move the object using its transform instead.

The reason why the object is not moving (at least I assume that is what you see on the screen) is that you are trying to set the object's transform's position and rigid body at the same **FixedUpdate** timestamp and updating transform on FixedUpdate is a lot far from any best practices out there. If you move the lines where you edit transform's position to **Update** method, it would **probably** move the object (depending on the framerate and timestamp of the FixedUpdate the game runs at).

What I would suggest is, either stop updating transform's positions on FixedUpdate and only use rb.MovePosition method, or remove FixedUpdate method and update the transform's positions on Update() method.

Also, make sure that you do not change the transform.position, rb.position or rb.velocity anywhere else inside that MonoBehaviour class for now, just to make sure that this piece of code works fine.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm adding something new to the project. Physics should make them easy. 
Player controls a sword. There are shurikens flying towards the player. Control the sword to hit the shurikens away.
From what I have learnt, the sword should be kinematic, and the shurikens should be dynamic.

Comment: If I only change FixedUpdate to Update, it should not move either. I have tested.

Comment: If I change all the transform.position to Rigidbody2D.MovePosition(), it is several hundred lines, so I want to find an easier way. If there is no way, just have to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Physics2D.SyncTransforms(); this function Work for me...
I needed use a Transform.Translate of a game object and then use Rigibody.MovePosition for a child game object. How the child received the translation of the parend, the rb.MovePosition just doesn't work... the update of the physics was enought between the two funtions.
Physics2D.SyncTransforms() allow update the physics for the transform.translation.